# Setting Kali Linux as default system instead of using it via VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, kali-linux

I just installed Kali Linux using VirtualBox. Is there any method to set Linux as my default system and get rid of the current one which is Windows 7? Or is it neccessary to delete both and install the fresh Linux on “empty” PC using CD?

Comment: I believe you're mistaken about what you just did with VirtualBox. Anyway, why Kali? I think it's a poor choice for a general purpose Linux.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that it's installing new operating system. Could you tell me please what actually it's all about?

About the choice, I got encouraged by watching presentations on youtube about its features, on the first sight it fitted perfectly expectations of a noob like me who watched "Matrix" few times too much in his life;d + I'm more than happy to get rid of my current system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** If you want to get rid of Windows 7, you need to get rid of Windows 7 entirely and reinstall Kali Linux as the main OS on your system. All VirtualBox does is act as a virtualization environment on Windows 7 that allows you to create virtual machines within Windows 7.

**Longer Answer:** VirtualBox is not magic. It is simply software that runs on an operating system—and in your case Windows 7—that allows you to run *another* operating system within your main operating system. So when you installed Kali Linux within VirtualBox, all you did is install an OS on a virtual machine.

So if you want Kali Linux to completely take over your system, you can’t just flick a switch and just decide to use Kali Linux as this point. Windows 7 is still your core/base OS on your machine. So what you would have to do is boot up your machine from a Kali Linux live install and have it wipe out all of the data on your system including Windows 7 as well as the VirtualBox you have installed on the system and any virtual machines connected to that VirtualBox install.